# Can I extract file metadata from a JavaScript file object?

Tags: javascript

I am working with the JavaScript File API and am getting a File object after the user drags a local file into the browser window. In this particular case, it is an mp3. The mp3 has standard metadata associated with it, such as artist, album, year, etc. I want to access that metadata. Is that possible?

Comment: The data you want is within the mp3 file. You need to parse the mp3 file for the media tags, something like [this will be helpful,](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags).

Comment: You dont even need any extra lib for that. [Check this out](https://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript)

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a bunch to both of you.